# MySQL - Remove A Portion of a String

Tags: mysql

I need to remove `http://www.`, `http://`, `https://www.`, and `https://` from a concatenated string and would like to know if there is a better way than using the REPLACE function. I'm guessing RegEx but I couldn't get it to work.

```
`out`= CONCAT(REPLACE( REPLACE( `PROGRAMNAME`, 'http://', '' ),'www.',''),'-', `NAME`
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a built-in regex replace function, but [such a user-defined function does exist](https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp). Without that, though, your way might be as simple as you can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a package of a UDF created to preform that type of operation with MySQL.

https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp

**Didn't see the comment when I posted my answer, sorry.